# Keras Create New Loss Function

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am looking to design a custom loss function for Keras model. The model itself is neural network that accepts a set of images and is supposed to run a regression to get an output, which is a value. Due to the physical conditions of the problem, I need to add a regularization term to the regular mse which would be calculated as $cos(y_{pred})*f(X_i)$, where $y_{pred}$ is the output of the neural network, $X_i$ is the training example used to calculate $y_{pred}$, $f$ is some function which would calculate a value based on the image.

My problem is how to get the $X_i$ from the model? Loss function is supposed to accept just two inputs: $y_{pred}$ and $y_{true}$ which are tensors.

Comment: You need to do it by hand with the Keras backend.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you included some more details. I know how to define custom loss function. But I do not know how to extract the training example that produced y_pred in the first place.

Comment: The easiest solution is to add whatever you need to the output of your model and then access it in the loss function. `Model(inputs=[..], outputs=[..,X_i])`

Comment: I am so sorry for asking, I am newbie to Keras. How would I attach something to the model’s output?